# CodeIgniter IE not storing sessions correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cart

I am using the Cart class of CodeIgniter, basically that's just sessions. Now, Safari is handling them perfectly fine and is doing what it is supposed to do. IE, on the other hand, does not store them.

So after a while of trying to fix this, I figured to add the sessions to the database.
Safari adds one result to the database with all fields filled out. Now IE. It adds around 5 items to the database with the row 'user_data' being empty.

This is the method adding the item to the cart;

```
    /**
* Method to add an item to the shopping cart.
*
* @access public
* @param integer $product_id
* @param string $name
* @param string $name_clean
* @param string $image
* @param integer $price
* @return boolean
* @since v0.1.0.0
*/
public function insert_item_cart($product_id='1',$name='default',$name_clean='default',$image='default',$price=1.00)
{
    // Prepare the data to be added to the cart.
    $data = array(
        'id'            => $product_id,
        'qty'           => 1,
        'name'          => $name,
        'price'         => $price,
        'options'       => array('name_clean' => $name_clean,'image' => $image)
    );

    // Insert the item to the cart.
    if ($this->cart->insert($data))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the Domain contains strange characters like "_" ? i had issues with Sessions in IE too and couldnt solve it in Domains like this...

Comment: name contains spaces, name_clean contains characters like "  -  " and image contains a dot.

Comment: no, i mean the domain.. eg: www.foo_bar.net

Comment: No, the domain does not, but the method inserting the things into the database contains one. http://www.domain.com/cart/insert_item/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by finding a website on Google after reading through 20 pages.
Fixed after changing

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

to

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
```